# What is meant by a "x bit hash function"

Tags: c++, hashtable, hash

What exactly is meant by a 64 bit hash function? Does it mean that it can map keys to atmost 2^64 locations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 64 bit hash function is a hash function resulting in a 64 bit output - which are 2^64 different values.

Comment: This answer could have been written as just "yes"

Comment: true - it would just be 27 characters too short :-)

Comment: The original question is in fact better: "**At most** 2^64". Some specialized hash functions may not be capable of producing all outputs, e.g. they may never hash to `0LL`.